# efficiently check two conditions on a dataset in python

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataset

I want to find the number of rows in a dataset which satisfy two conditions:

```
counter = len(train[(train['tag'] == label) & (train['word'] == word)])
```

but it takes a long time to compute it based on the volume of data I have and number of times I want to perform it.

Is there any other faster way?

update:
@jezrael solution, nearly tripled its speed, but still takes too long.

it is the more completed code!

```
for index, row in tqdm(test.iterrows()):
word = row['word']
for label in labels:
    temp1 = train.eval('tag == @label and word == @word').sum()/labelDict[label]
    temp2 = train.eval('tag == @label and tag1 == @LastLable').sum()/labelDict[label]
    temp = temp1 * temp2
    if max > temp:
        max = temp
        bestLabel = label
```

Comment: `&` does not mean 'boolean and' in python, it means bitwise-and.

Comment: @TomDalton - it is pandas, it is bitwise AND and working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) working with [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#how-it-works) and sum `True`s:

```
counter = train.eval('tag == @label and word == @word').sum()
```

Another solution, slowier:

```
counter = ((train['tag'] == label) & (train['word'] == word)).sum()
```

Performance:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'tag':list('abaaea'),
                     'word':list('baabbb')})

print (train)

#600k rows
train = pd.concat([train] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

label = 'a'
word = 'b'

In [214]: %timeit (((train['tag'] == label) & (train['word'] == word)).sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 84.6 ms per loop

In [215]: %timeit (train.eval('tag == @label and word == @word').sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 25.8 ms per loop

In [216]: %timeit (len(train[(train['tag'] == label) & (train['word'] == word)]))
10 loops, best of 3: 90.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution nearly tripled its speed, but still takes long time! :(

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - What means long time?

Comment: about 4 iteration/second in a dataset with 65,000 rows. ( I do it about 20 times for each row)

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - Unfortunately I have no idea

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - Why do you it 20 times? Is not possible only once?

Comment: I have to find the most probable tag for each word in the test set (contains 65,000 words) using their distribution on the training data (contains 200,000 words) for 10 different tags (two calculation for each tag).

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - hmmm, is possible show your code?

Comment: @ jezrael - I put it in the question.

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - not so easy, one question - `labels` are from `row` like `labels= row['labels']` ?

Comment: @ jezrael- it is a predefined set containing unique tags - a list containing 10 items-

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - and from `test` DataFrame need only `word` column values?

Comment: @ jezrael - word, tag and tag1

Comment: I think `train`, not `test`.

Comment: @EhsanMehralian - are data confidental?